# Instagram API with PHP

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagramapi-mgp25, instagram-story

I have an application where I am using Facebook,Linkedin and Twitter Api's to post on the respective platforms.Now I am deciding to use Instagram to start posting using their Api but I have not found any good articles to implement their Api.

Moreover I have read somewhere that it is not possible to post media contents using Instagram Api's. Is it true or we can now use Instagram to share media contents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it's only possible to post comments via the Instagram Graph API. You cannot post media.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media

IG Media
Represents and Instagram photo, video, story, or album.

Creating
This operation is not supported. To create an IG Comment, use the POST /{ig-media-id}/comments endpoint instead.

However there is a new publishing beta program you must be invited into:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media

Creates a media container for a photo IG Media object. This endpoint is only available to partners in the Content Publishing API beta program.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

Comment: Thanks for the replay !!!! I have another doubt that do I need to both Facebook Marketing Partner and Instagram Partner or if becoming only Facebook Marketing Partner will work? How can I check if a account is included in Facebook Marketing Partner or not? Actually the FB account is of someone other and they don't know whether it Facebook Marketing partner is active in that or not.

Comment: following @Pawanlakhera did you find answer ? how to register Facebook marketing partner or Instagram ?

Comment: I haven't received any update from Facebook side for this @PramodTiwari